# Which Javascript event signifies that an Angular SPA has finished a page load?

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Google Tag Manager and VWO, I am injecting changes to our Angular SPA for Growth Hacking purposes. However, I've had issues with firing my change Javascript after a given page is fully rendered.

Is there an event or set of events that reliably signify that the page has finished loading, which will also fire on page transition? I would like to achieve this without relying upon Angular hooks, but rather purely as client-side Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Angular hooks for such operation.

> **AfterContentInit** : A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has fully initialized all content of a directive. Define an ngAfterContentInit() method to handle any additional initialization tasks.

> **AfterViewInit** : A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view. Define an ngAfterViewInit() method to handle any additional initialization tasks.

for more information, refer to angular documentation
[AfterContentInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit),
[AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)